# Counting number of span stored inside variable in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically trying to count the number of spans which is stored inside `items` variable but the `length` is always returning `0`

```
var items = '<br><span class="holiday">Buddha Jayanti</span><br><span class="workingDay">Shiva Ratri</span>';

var length = $(items).find('span').length;
alert(length); //returning 0
```

Is there somthing am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `span` are at the root of the element set, so `.find()` will not return any elements, you need to use [.filter()](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) instead

```js
var items = '<br><span class="holiday">Buddha Jayanti</span><br><span class="workingDay">Shiva Ratri</span>';

var length = $(items).filter('span').length;
snippet.log(length);
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

If there is a possibility to have descendant `span` elements also then, another option is

```js
var items = '<br><span class="holiday">Buddha Jayanti</span><br><span class="workingDay">Shiva Ratri</span><div><br><span class="workingDay">some value</span></div>';

var length = $('<div />', {
  html: items
}).find('span').length;
snippet.log(length);
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```